# What is a "standard" boot camp partition setup?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, upgrade, partition, recovery

I am trying to upgrade to 10.10(.4) - currently I am at 10.9.5.  I had previously done some "creative" :) partitioning of my rMBP SSD - everything was working fine, running Boot Camp as well.  However, the 10.10 installer didn't like my partitioning scheme (I did want to have a Recovery partition included), so I reduced the system back down to just the OS X (HFS+) partition and the Boot Camp (NTFS) partition.  However, in that re-partitioning, the "Recovery HD" partition become unhidden (everything still functions as it should).

Now when I attempt the upgrade, the installer is still giving me grief about the state of the HD with the message:

> **Some features of OS X 10.10 are not supported for the disk "Mac HD"**
>
> Features such as FileVault and Recovery Mode won't be available of you install 10.10 on this disk. To learn more, click More Info. To continue with the installation, click Continue.

I suppose it is likely I am getting this due to the fact that the Recovery HD is no longer hidden.  I would prefer to have the 10.10 recovery partition on the SSD if at all possible.

So - if I blow away the Recovery HD partition, will the installer Do the Right Thing and put a new Yosemite one in?  Maybe it will do so anyway?  Maybe do a reinstall of 10.9.5 so that (maybe?) hides the Recovery partition? Are there some flags I can set to manually hide the Recovery HD partition? (FBOW I am very familiar with GPartEd and gdisk.) Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did a bit more searching and came across [this page](http://automatica.com.au/2013/11/hide-recovery-hd-after-cloning-an-os-x-installation/#comment-155352) which gave me the correct commands to hide the recover partition:

```
%mount (find the partition of "Recovery HD")
%diskutil unmount <partition>  (in my case: /dev/disk0s3 )
%sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk0s3 -settype Apple_Boot
```

After this, I verified I could boot into all OSes (I could), went back to Yosemite installer and it approved of my partition scheme.  Everything is working great in 10.10 now.